# overwriting specific files in a directory tree recursively

Tags: windows, linux, command-line, shell, batch-file

I would like to overwrite files in a directory tree, recursively.

The ones I would like to overwrite match the filename **"x_alpha*.png"** and have a size **exactly 456 bytes**.

Is there any way to search for these recursively in a directory tree, and overwrite them with a reference file, for example `"e:\mydir\good.png"`

I am using Windows 7, but I have [UnxUtils](http://unxutils.sourceforge.net/), so I can use those too.

What I am looking for is something like this, generated automatically:

```
copy /y e:\mydir\good.png e:\mydir\a\b\c\x_alpha0023.png
copy /y e:\mydir\good.png e:\mydir\e\f\g\x_alpha0045.png
copy /y e:\mydir\good.png e:\mydir\h\x_alpha0248.png
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also do this in Power Shell since you are using Windows 7.

```
dir -recurse x_alpha*.png | where-object { $_.Length -eq 456 } | foreach-object { copy-item -force e:\mydir\good.png $_.FullName }
dir -recurse x_alpha*.png   (to see the results)
```

Answer (score 1):

I do not know UnxUtils, but it can be done with cygwin with:

```
find /cygdrive/e/mydir/ -type f -name "x_alpha*.png" -size 456c -exec cp /cygdrive/e/mydir/good.png {} \;
```

You could probably extrapolate how to do this with UnxUtils.

Test it first by running the following before overwriting files:

```
find /cygdrive/e/mydir/ -type f -name "x_alpha*.png" -size 456c
```